# Python attribute error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Tags: python, pandas

for the last line, there's the error, I cannot figure out why there's the attribute error

```
import pandas as pd

name = pd.read_csv('location', encoding='latin1')
name['Name'] = name['Name'].str.lower()
movie_name = name['Name'].replace(" ", "_")

try:
URL = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/ + movie_name"
except:
  pass

df = URL
df.to_csv('url.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Can you explain more what are you trying to do please, Here you are calling a method "to_csv" which applies to pandas DataFrame but your URL is a string. I think there is a missing instruction. You are missing the  call to a REST api with the URLthat will return a DataFrame but in your case it will not do that.

Comment: To be clear, [edit] this question and tell us what you want to do and show what you have tried. If there is an error it should be in the body of the question as formatted text. Also show what debugging steps you have taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the dataframe `df` to `URL`, you make it contain `"https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/ + movie_name"`. On another note, you have to move the second `"` symbol to before the `+` operation to function: `"https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/" + movie_name`.

Comment: I am guessing that your indentation of `URL = ..` is only displayed incorrectly here on Stackoverflow, but please make sure that it *is* indented once compared to `try`.

Comment: It worked!!!! I am a newbie to python, thanks a loooot!!!

Comment: I indented in Jupyter, thanks for reminding me that. I have one more question, I used "replace" but did not work, would you please have a look at it? The code is : movie_name = name['Name'].replace(" ", "_")

Comment: You're welcome! :) To fix the issue with the replace method, you have to annotate the strings with an `r` for regex like so `r"<your regex string>"` and add a parameter `regex=True` to tell pandas that you want to use a regex. Without naming the regex parameter this would look like this: `replace(r" ", r"_", True)`.

Comment: If the answer helped you, I would appreciate it, if you could accept it here on Stackoverflow to mark the question as resolved.